# in that regard, we are failing

Tags: word-meaning

> Francis Collins (director of NIH): Well, I'm afraid we should not really have ever gotten in the place we are. So, in that regard, yes, **we are failing**.
> We have vaccines that we know are highly effective and safe. And yet half the country is still not fully vaccinated.

Source:  [image]

Does "we are failing" mean "we are not successful (in fighting against the COVID pandemic)"?  That is, "failing" just means "being unsuccessful"; and it particularly refers to "being unsuccessful in fighting the COVID" than otherwise. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Please type out the content of the image you have inserted, or as much as you think the question requires. Questions must be searchable for this site to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You can fail at a great deal of things. In this case, we are failing to meet a goal.

> We are failing to vaccinate the population

> We are failing at vaccinating the population

> We are failing in our vaccination efforts

Here are a few examples of how we can use `failing`.